# Software audio mixer

Tags: audio, alsa

I need to be able to simultaneously play several files on my **headless** Raspberry Pi and dynamically changing their volumes, preferably with Python.

I managed to get it to work with the [swmixer](https://github.com/nwhitehead/swmixer) Python library but it is based on pyaudio (itself based on portaudio) which is known to stutter on the BCM chipset of the Pi.

[sounddevice & soundfile](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.9/) libraries seems to play flawlessly but I'd have to port swmixer to use it instead of pyaudio and that's a lot of work.

Then I thought of going lower-level and use ALSA utils such as `aplay` to play and `amixer` to change the volume, using dmix to create a software mixer, but right now I can't make dmix work even with [the official base configuration](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#dmix).

**What other alternatives do I have to programmatically play/pause/stop and change volume of multiple tracks on a headless Raspberry Pi?**

Answer (score 1):

Pulse Audio was designed specifically for this use case.

Here is the [Pulse Audio API Documentation](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/).

Here is a [Pulse Audio Python Library](https://github.com/Valodim/python-pulseaudio).